# extract the dimensions from the head lines of text file

Tags: python, numpy

Please see following attached image showing the format of the text file. I need to extract the dimensions of data matrix indicated by the first line in the file, here 49 * 70 * 1 for the case shown by the image. Note that the length of name "gd_fac" can be varying. How can I extract these numbers as integers?  I am using Python 3.6.

[image: Text file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specification is not very clear. I am assuming that the information you want will always be in the first line, and always be in parenthesis. After that:

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    line = infile.readline()
    string = line[line.find('(')+1:line.find(')')]
    lst = string.split('x')
```

This will create the list `lst = [49, 70, 1]`.

What is happening here:
First I open the file (you will need to replace `filename` with the name of your file, as a string. The `with ... as ...` structure ensures that the file is closed after use. Then I read the first line. After that. I select only the parts of that line that fall after the open paren `(`, and before the close paren `)`. Finally, I break the string into parts, with the character `x` as the separator. This creates a list that contains the values in the first line of the file, which fall between parenthesis, and are separated by `x`.

Comment: I like your solution. =)

Comment: upvoted for your nice answer. Mines a little longer you really made it nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

What this does is it looks for "gd_fac"
then if it's there is removes all the unneeded stuff and replaces it with just what you want.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if("gd_fac" in line):
                line = line.replace("gd_fac", "")
                line = line.replace("x", "*")
                line = line.replace("(","")
                line = line.replace(")","")
                print (line)
                break
```

**OUTPUT:** "49x70x1"

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that length of 'gd_fac' van be variable, best solution will be using Regular Expression.

```
import re
with open("a.txt") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if '(' in line and ')' in line:
            dimension =  re.findall(r'.*\((.*)\)',line)[0]
            break
print dimension
```

**Output:**

```
'49x70x1'
```